# Is there any way I can make "protected" typedef's in C?

Tags: c, types, typedef, protected, information-hiding

if you want to cut to the chase, please skip down to the last two paragraphs. If you're interested in my predicament and the steps I've taken to solve it, continue reading directly below.

I am currently developing portions of a C library as part of my internship. So naturally, there are some parts of code which should not be accessible to the user while others should be. I am basically developing several architecture-optimized random number generators (RNG's)(uniform, Gaussian, and exponential distributed numbers). The latter two RNG's depend on the uniform generator , which is in a different kernel (project). So, in the case that the user wants to use more than one RNG, I want to make sure I'm not duplicating code needlessly since we are constrained with memory (no point in having the same function defined multiple times at different addresses in the code segment).

Now here's where the problem arises. The convention for all other kernels in the library is that we have a two header files and two C files (one each for the natural C implementation and the optimized C version (which may use some intrinsic functions and assembly and/or have some restrictions to make it faster and better for our architecture). This is followed by another C file (a testbench) where our main function is located and it tests both implementations and compares the results. With that said, we cannot really add an additional header file for private or protected items nor can we add a global header file for all these generators.

To combat this restriction, I used **extern** functions and **extern const int**'s in the C files which depend on the uniform RNG rather than **#define**'s at the top of each C file in order to make the code more portable and easily modified in one place. This worked for the most part.

However, the tricky bit is that we are using an internal type within these kernels (which should not be seen by the user and should not be placed in the header file). Again, for portability, I would like to be able to change the definition of this **typedef** in one place rather than in multiple places in multiple kernels since the library may be used for another platform later on and for the algorithms to work it is critical that I use 32-bit types.

So basically I'm wondering if there's any way I can make a **typedef** "protected" in C. That is, I need it to be visible among all C files which need it, but invisible to the user. It can be in one of the header files, but must not be visible to the user who will be including that header file in his/her project, whatever that may be.

============================***Edit***================================ 
I should also note that the typedef I am using is an unsigned int. so

**typedef unsigned int** *myType*

No structures involved.

============================***Super Edit***========================== 
The use of stdint.h is also forbidden :(

Comment: `typedef struct foo { int bar; } foo;` in `<inernal.h>`, then only expose `<non-internal.h>` to the user.

Comment: But again, I can't really add another header file to the kernel (for historical reasons with the rest of the library). Otherwise this whole debacle would be easier. Unfortunately for me (fortunately for him), the supervisor is on vacation in Europe, so I can't really ask him if I can change the file structure. The internal type itself has stirred up some debate about the historical practices. Eventually, it was decided that it should be used only internally and now here I sit: smug as a bug on a rug; no dice bub!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am expanding on [Jens Gustedt’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17604200/298225) since the OP still has questions.

First, it is unclear why you have separate header files for the two implementations (“natural C” and “optimized C”). If they implement the same API, one header should serve for either.

Jens Gustedt’s recommendation is that you declare a `struct foo` in the header but define it only in the C source file for the implementation and not in the header. A `struct` declared in this way is an incomplete type, and source code that can only see the declaration, and not the definition, cannot see what is in the type. It can, however, use pointers to the type.

The declaration of an incomplete `struct` may be as simple as `struct foo`. You can also define a type, such as `typedef struct foo foo;` or `typedef struct foo Mytype;`, and you can define a type that is a pointer to the `struct`, such as `typedef struct foo *FooPointer;`. However, these are merely for convenience. They do not alter the basic notion, that there is a `struct foo` that API users cannot see into but that they can have pointers to.

Inside the implementation, you would fully define the `struct`. If you want an `unsigned int` in the `struct`, you would use:

```
struct foo
{
    unsigned int x;
};
```

In general, you define the `struct foo` to contain whatever data you like.

Since the API user cannot define `struct foo`, you must provide functions to create and destroy objects of this type as necessary. Thus, you would likely have a function declared as `extern struct foo *FooAlloc(some parameters);`. The function creates a `struct foo` object (likely by calling `malloc` or a related function), initializes it with data from the parameters, and returns a pointer to the object (or NULL if the creation or initialization fails). You would also have a function `extern void FooFree(struct foo *p);` that frees a `struct foo` object. You might also have functions to reset, set, or alter the state of a foo object, functions to copy foo objects, and functions to report about foo objects.

Your implementations could also define some global `struct foo` objects that could be visible (essentially by address only) to API users. As a matter of good design, this should be done only for certain special purposes, such as to provide instances of `struct foo` objects with special meanings, such as a constant object with a permanent “initial state” for copying.

Your two implementations, the “natural C” and the “optimized C” implementations may have different definitions for the `struct foo`, provided they are not both used in a program together. (That is, each entire program is compiled with one implementation or the other, not both. If necessary, you could mangle both into a program by using a union, but it is preferable to avoid that.)

This is not a singleton approach.

Comment: I like the expanded ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Just do

```
typedef struct foo foo;
```

These are two declarations, a forward declaration of a `struct` and a type alias with the same name. Forward declared `struct` can be used to nothing else than to define pointers to them. This should give you enough abstraction and type safety.

In all your interfaces you'd have

```
extern void proc(foo* a);
```

and you'd have to provide functions

```
extern foo* foo_alloc(size_t n);
extern void foo_free(foo* a);
```

This would bind your users as well as your library to always use the same `struct`. Thereby the implementation of `foo` is completely hidden to the API users. You could even one day to decide to use something different than a `struct` since users should use `foo` without the `struct` keyword.

**Edit:** Just a `typedef` to some kind of integer wouldn't help you much, because these are only aliases for types. All your types aliased to `unsigned` could be used interchangeably. One way around this would be to encapsulate them inside a `struct`. This would make your internal code a bit ugly, but the generated object code should be exactly the same with a good modern compiler.

Comment: Would I be able to do this with an unsigned int typedef as I noted in my edit (sorry, couldn't edit fast enough for your response)?

Comment: Also, if you're suggesting a Singleton approach, that's not quite what I'm looking for since I need multiple unsigned 32-bit numbers (also using stdint.h is forbidden too). I just need the type itself accessible to all my C files.